# Overlap custom TileLayer with satellite layer in Goolge MAP API

Tags: layers, google-maps

I've added a new `mapTypes` TileLayer (png tiles, transparent background) into my `mapOptions` that ables me to switch from others `mapTypes` to the new one, using button option. At the moment, when I change of `mapTypes` the new layer appears and the old layer disappears ==> I can't use 2 layers at the same time.

How can I overlap 2 layers into one `mapTypes` ? To understand the method I would like to overlap Satellite (from google) and the new one.

The code I use ables me to changes of layer, but it doesn't overlap: Note: I use an API KEY that I can't provide..

```
   <script>                                            
         var map;
         function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {
                lat: 52.1933892,
                lng: 0.1364648
            }
                 mapTypeControl: true,
                 mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'Newlayer']
                }
            });
            var tiledLayer=new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                    getTileUrl: function(tileCoord,zoom) {
                        var url="API/GET/WMTS+tileCoord.x+tileCoord.z+zoom+png";
                        return url;                     
                    },
                    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
                    name: "New layer",
                    maxZoom: 18
            });     
                 map.mapTypes.set('Newlayer',tiledLayer);
       } // INIT END
    </script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```